# Como usar um Spinner em um AlertDialog?

Tags: android, dialog

Estou em duvida como colocar um spinner em um AlertDialog, já tenho os códigos prontos, só falta inserir o spinner.

Array:

```
<string-array name="categoria_array">
    <item>Aeroporto</item>
    <item>Bar</item>
    <item>Casa Noturna</item>
    <item>Cinema</item>
    <item>Colégio</item>
    <item>Loja</item>
    <item>Museu</item>
    <item>Parque</item>
    <item>Restaurante</item>
    <item>Rodoviárias</item>
    <item>Shoppings</item>
    <item>Supermercado</item>
    <item>Teatro</item>
    <item>Universidade</item>
    <item>Outro</item>
</string-array>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="NOVA LOCALIZAÇÃO"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/titulo"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_transp_black_redond"
        android:hint="  Nome do Local"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_endereco"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/edt_nome"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_transp_black_redond"
        android:hint="  Endereço"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_website"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/edt_endereco"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:hint="  WebSite"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:inputType="textWebEditText"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_transp_black_redond"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_telefone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/edt_website"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:hint="  Telefone"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_transp_black_redond"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_catogorias"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edt_telefone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Metodo AlertDialog:

```
private void chamarDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_newcheckin, null));
    //Dialog dialog = builder.show();
    //dialog.dismiss(); fecha o dialog
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cliked OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return;
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Qual é exactamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: Se preciso criar uma classe pra o spinner ou se tem como chamar ele no Dialog, se sim como eu faria isso. Não tenho muita experiência em android, to começando agora

Comment: Está correto. Você está com dúvida em como obter o valor do spinner é isso?

Comment: Tipo eu fiz o array com os valores, mas como vou fazer esse valores aparecer no spinner, no caso minha duvida é como carregar o spinner com os valores do array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necessita de criar um [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) que faça a ligação do *string-array* com o *Spinner*.

A classe [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) tem o método estático [createFromResource()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) que cria um *adapter* a partir de um *string-array*.
Atribua o *adapter* criado ao *Spinner* usando o método [setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.SpinnerAdapter%29).

Altere o método `chamarDialog()` desta forma:

```
private void chamarDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    //Cria a view a ser utilizada no dialog
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_newcheckin, null);

    //Obtém uma referencia ao Spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_catogorias);

    //Cria o Adapter
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.categoria_array,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);//ou android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

    //Atribui o adapter ao spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cliked OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return;
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Deu erro de execução:
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                                   at br.com.projeto.caminhossembarreiras.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)"

Comment: Pois, não pode ser no onCreate() porque o spinner está no dialog. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Ok, obrigado por toda ajuda que está passando!

Comment: Já viu a resposta depois da alteração? É isto que procurava? Se sim veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a forma de proceder quando uma resposta te foi útil.